# In clash of clans, if you place a wall next to a large stone, can troops walk between the wall and stone?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In clash of clans, if you place a wall next to a large stone, can troops walk between the wall and stone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Troops can be spawned on and walk through any obstacles and decorations, they cannot be used as a tactical advantage.

Of course, placing buildings near them can cover them with the "protected" area that prevents spawning, unlike the map edge.